# Unable to run Reporting Services 2017 on Azure instance running SQL Server 2017 Web edition

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm running this version of SQL Server on an Azure instance:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  
Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Per the description for the instance ('SQL Server 2017 Web on Windows Server 2016'):

This image contains the Web edition of SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016. This provides a low-cost database solution for medium-size web applications. It includes the core database engine and Management Studio for integrated administration and development. Also includes basic versions of Reporting Services for web reports, Integration Services for moving and transforming data, and Analysis Services for data mining. We recommend that you use a virtual machine size of DS12 or higher.

When I attempt to connect / configure using the 'Report Services Configuration Manager', I'm unable to 'find' the Report server instance in the 'Reporting Services Configuration Connection' dialog. I.e. the 'Report Server Instance' had not values to choose from.

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services (note three editions were available - Eval, Developer, & Express - tried each edition - uninstalling each version before trying the next)

When I went to configure the Reporting Services using the 'Report Server Configuration Manager' I got to the 'Change Database' tab. At the point that I am assigning the database engine to the reporting services I get the error:

> The database engine instance you selected is not valid for this edition of report server

Note I'm running the Web edition of SQL Server, but I'm not seeing an option to select that in the installation of the report services

Thoughts re what I'm missing?

I Ended up reverting back to SQL 2016 to go around the issue

Comment: What do you mean when you say you were unable to 'find' the report server instance? Was the service running? What do you mean by saying you installed Reporting services (i.e. from which media) and what do yo umean by saying Eval, Developer and Express were all installed? YOu mean you installed 3 more editions of sql server on top of the one installed in the Azure VM? Which edition of SQL Server were you trying to choose to store your databases?

Comment: Update the question to clarify

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar issue. I tried to get the SQL Server key from a PowerShell script as well, but they didn't work for SQL Server 2017 Web Edition.

So the solution was much easier than I expected.

1. Go to the C: drive of your VM. You will find SQL Setup there.
2. Run the setup to start a new standalone installation. When you will be on product key page it will display the License Key.
3. Copy that key and put it into your Reporting Services Installation.

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks! VLSC wouldn't give me a key for web edition SSRS standalone installation so I used this method.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically saying you cannot use the edition of your SQL Server Engine (in this case, Web edition) for SQL Server Reporting Services 2017. Can you try a different edition of SQL Server?

**Update:**
You can learn more about supported editions of Database Engine you can use for each different type of edition of Reporting Services 2017 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016. While some of the content may not be applicable for SSRS 2017, the bits which are applicable are still accurate.